# Best way to schedule large amount of tasks in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm currently building an API in Laravel (PHP) for retrieving prices from different hosts. There are currently 756 different 'coins' with different hosts to retrieve the prices from.

For example: Coin X

Host 1
Host 2
Host 3 
-- up to 30 hosts

Coin Y

Host 1
Host 4
Host 5 -- up to 30 hosts
etc.

The problem here is, that ideally each coin should be updated every 10 seconds. This means that each coin needs to call all of its hosts, calculate the average price, save the price in the DB and finally save a JSON file with the total history of the coin. (Perhaps it would be better to also save the current price as JSON to save some time)

I've tried to putting all of this in a class for each host, but the execution time is way too long (around 5 minutes using CURL).

I'm thinking to create a task (cron job) for each coin. This way the 'updating' of the coins can go in sync (multiple coins at once). But i'm not quitte sure this would be the best way.

What approach would you guys recommend? All tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overall update time is going to be limited by number of coins x individual host update speed. You might want to time how long one (or avg) request takes (with script) to see just how long the whole thing will take. As, if it will likely take too long, doing them one after the other, you will have to set it up to do parallel (at same time) requests.

Comment: Hi Hayden, Thanks for anwsering. The average time for 1 request is approx. 500 - 700 ms. If I understand it correctly, would you suggest to put all the requests in a CURL_MULTI ? I haven't tested that out yet, but a good call.

Comment: I have not had much to do with CURL (only single simple requests), without googling i would have no idea if it can do simultaneous requests at the same time. But any way you can do this will be worth a try. You will still likely need a cron job to call the php script at intervals, whether you can do multi calls in one function or make multi calls of a function.

Comment: Wow, i've just run the whole process with curl_multi and downscaled the time to 12 seconds. This is great. I can work further from here. Many thanks Hayden!

Comment: No problem, I cant say i did much, but i do know that even coming here and asking, putting your thoughts into words can be enough to work it out yourself sometimes, that has happened to me before, and you pretty much did that yourself. :)

Comment: Also a word of note, you will likely need some check that a current request is not still ongoing for a particular server, before starting a new one, as I imagine if there was a significant delay with one of them, you could end up with a lot of connection attempts , flooding the server, and chewing up your process count.

Comment: Or set a reasonable time out compared with how regularly you will make a request.

Comment: Yeah, I've got to tweak the options a bit for the best way to work (curl_setopt). But you saying the word parallel made my google search a lot better, so your help is much appreciated :).